# reactjs: how to convert twitters key + secret string to base64

Tags: reactjs, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use rest api of twitter. Presently i want to use the search api. For that I only need the `application only authentication`. I am using reactjs frontend. I am using the react library inside the html. The following is the code to create a combined key + secret. I dont know how to convert to base64.

```
            var key = "*****************";
            var secret = "******************";
            var cat = key +":"+secret;
            var credentials = ?? How to convert cat to base64 ??
```

This is the full code. Let me know which libraries i have to include.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Twitter API</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">

    class Module extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          var key = "*****************";
          var secret = "******************";
          var cat = key +":"+secret;
          var credentials = cat



          this.state = {
            bearer_token:"XXXXXXXXXXX"
          }

          this.handleClickGettoken = this.handleClickGettoken.bind(this)

      }

      handleClickGettoken(){
          var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token';
          axios({ url: url,
              method:'POST',
              headers: {
                  "Authorization": "Basic " + this.credentials,
                  "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
              },
              body: "grant_type=client_credentials"
          })
          .then(function(response) {
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        bearer_token: response
                      })
                    )
          });
      }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
            <p>{ this.state.bearer_token }</p>
            <button  onClick={this.handleClickGettoken}>GetBearerToken</button>
            </div>

          );
        }
      }

  ReactDOM.render(
      <Module />,
      document.getElementById('root')
  );
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var credentials = new Buffer(cat).toString('base64');
```

If 'Buffer' is not available, try:

```
var credentials = window.btoa(cat);
```

Comment: how to add buffer. I am not using npm.

Comment: i am doing console.log(credentials). it shows no output

Comment: It looks like someone created a react native implementation of btoa - https://snack.expo.io/BktW0xdje

Comment: ok. whats the difference between  window.btoa(cat) and https://snack.expo.io/BktW0xdje

Comment: well window.btoa is vanilla js available to most browsers (including IE10 and up). It should just be available. If you were still having issues getting anything to work, your could borrow that code and inline your own version, if window.btoa is working, that is your easiest solution.

Comment: window.btoa(cat) is working for me. SO i will stick to it